# Is the "partition is misaligned error" legit? how should I handle?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“the partition is misaligned” error in Disk Utility - should I repartition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30071/the-partition-is-misaligned-error-in-disk-utility-should-i-repartition)

I just migrated to a new 750GB [Seagate Momentus](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?name=st9750420as-momentus-7200-sata-3gbs-750-gb-hd&vgnextoid=ccb380c31fea6210VgnVCM1000001a48090aRCRD&vgnextchannel=f424072516d8c010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD#tTabContentSpecifications) drive on my Thinkpad X201. I'd cloned the orginal 500GB drive using Clonezilla, and then repartitioned with Gparted Live. I was successful in growing my partitions after I deleted and recreated the swap drive per this thread: [Advice on Moving Partitions with Gparted After Cloning Drive to a larger one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63932/advice-on-moving-partitions-with-gparted-after-cloning-drive-to-a-larger-one/63953#63953)

After booting into the newly partitioned environment I went to Disk Utility to check on the drive, and was greeted with the warning: "the partition is misaligned by 512 bytes etc...

[image]

The system seems fine, and I'm seeing conflicting information out there regarding the validity of this warning... I still have the original drive and can easily go back if necessary. Any feedback is appreciated.